# Views get modified are when republishing a modified infopath form to a forms library

Tags: 2010, infopath, list-view, forms-library

There is a complex infopath 2010 form with several promoted fields. The form is published as a web form to a forms library on a SP2010 farm.

There are 5 similar forms libs on different webs, each with its own form. the forms differ in the submit url only, bcause I did not find a way to set the submit target lib dynamically without code.
When I need to modify the form, I edit one reference form, change the submit target lib and publish it to the according forms lib.

Now I noticed that publishing a form affects the views of the according forms libs, exept the one with the reference form. The vierws lose their filter criteria and other thigs, it seems that they are resetted to an earlier version.

This is very annoying, why does that happen?

UPDATE:
The form has a promoted field "Status". It seems that this field collides with a site column of the same name. Can that be the problem?

UPDATE:
The Status field bekomes Status0. I decided to rename the promoted field to "stat" in the InfoPath form options and republish it. But no change. Why?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: Are the forms in different site collections? If that's true, you can use the same form with different data connection files to change the submit target ...

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think InfoPath saves the IDs (GUIDs) of the promoted fields it creates. So when you published your form to five targets, field A was created with a different ID in each library. InfoPath saved the ID in the file, but overwrote the ID from the last save. So now he searches the last ID he saved, doesn't find it and creates the promoted field anew.

Comment: Thanks, the forms are all in one site collection but in parallel webs.